# docker-compose up issues on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm following this tutorial from the Docker Compose docs : https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

I'm at Step 4- Build and run your app with Compose

However, whenever I type in

> docker-compose up

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.

So I tried

> docker-machine start default

and I got the following error

> Host does not exist: "default"

And on running docker-machine ls I get

> ubuntu@thething:~/composetest$ docker-machine ls
>
> NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS

So I tried

> ubuntu@thething:~/composetest$ docker-machine create --driver default
>
> Driver "default" not found. Do you have the plugin binary "docker-machine-driver-default" accessible in your PATH?

I've googled a lot, but can't find something specific for Ubuntu. Please help!

Comment: i try to help you a little. 
`docker-machine` tool need only for mac and windolws. If you use ubuntu avoid it.
when you execute `docker-compose up` just try to add `sudo`. May be your user don't has permission to connect to docker service.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That fixed it!